# Copy cell data from TableView to clipboard

Tags: javafx-8

I have a TableView with -depending on user input- 4 to 10 columns. I want to be able to copy selected cells to the system clipboard. I tried this piece of code that I found in SO, but `position.getColumn()` always returns -1, so it doesn´t work. Also, `table.getSelectionModel().getSelectedCells()` returns only as many items as there are rows. I expected it to return one item per cell instead. Can someone point out my error?

```
TableView<TableEntry> table = new TableView<>();
        //copy to clipboard
        table.setOnKeyPressed(e -> {
            if (e.getCode() == KeyCode.C && e.isControlDown()) {
                StringBuilder clipboardString = new StringBuilder();

                ObservableList<TablePosition> positionList = table.getSelectionModel().getSelectedCells();

                int prevRow = -1;

                for (TablePosition position : positionList) {

                    int row = position.getRow();
                    int col = position.getColumn();


                    Object cell = (Object) table.getColumns().get(col).getCellData(row);

                    // null-check: provide empty string for nulls
                    if (cell == null) {
                        cell = "";
                    }

                    // determine whether we advance in a row (tab) or a column
                    // (newline).
                    if (prevRow == row) {

                        clipboardString.append('\t');

                    } else if (prevRow != -1) {

                        clipboardString.append('\n');

                    }

                    // create string from cell
                    String text = cell.toString();

                    // add new item to clipboard
                    clipboardString.append(text);

                    // remember previous
                    prevRow = row;
                }

                // create clipboard content
                final ClipboardContent clipboardContent = new ClipboardContent();
                clipboardContent.putString(clipboardString.toString());

                // set clipboard content
                Clipboard.getSystemClipboard().setContent(clipboardContent);
            }

        });
```

Comment: Do you have cell selection enabled, or is the selection just row-based?

Comment: @James_D table.getSelectionModel().selectionModeProperty().set(SelectionMode.MULTIPLE); Only other option in the SelectionMode.enum is SINGLE.

Comment: @Elltz I tried it, didn´t work. It still returns only one TablePosition per row, with colindex = -1

Comment: @James_D You were right. table.getSelectionModel().setCellSelectionEnabled(true); did the trick. Silly mistake, but it was my first TableView. Thanks. If you make an answer out of it, I´ll check it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

James_D nailed it in the comment; the cell selection needs to be enabled:

```
table.getSelectionModel().setCellSelectionEnabled(true)
```

Answer (score 3):

This is a [useful link](https://respostas.guj.com.br/47439-habilitar-copypaste-tableview-funcionando-duvida-editar-funcionalidade)
And this is my answer:

```
    @FXML
    public void copyText() {
        String elementTableSelected = messageTable.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem().getNotificationsLanguage().esProperty().getValue();
        final Clipboard clipboard = Clipboard.getSystemClipboard();
        final ClipboardContent content = new ClipboardContent();
        content.putString(elementTableSelected);
        clipboard.setContent(content);
        System.out.println(elementTableSelected);
    }
```